# Computing $\int{2\sec^3xdx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I attempted to solve this problem by taking the two out of the integral. Then, I changed $\sec^3(x)$ to $\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)\cos(x)}$ and attempted to replace $\cos^2(x)$ with $1 - \sin^2(x)$.

However, I do not know where to go from here. Any insight, hints, tips, or answers would be fantastic.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: $\sec^2{x} = (d/dx) \tan{x}$.  Then use integration by parts.

Comment: consider splitting $sec^3x$ to $secxsec^2x$ then employ integration by parts as suggested by ron, note which terms you want to differentiate and integrate depending on known results you should have.

Comment: Thank you very much Ron and Whizkid, that helped tremendously

Comment: [This document](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m121/secx.pdf) could also be helpful.

Comment: That document was very helpful as well.

Comment: Most calculus textbooks show step-by-step how to integrate the odd powers of $\sec x$. Look it up in the section on trigonometric integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\sec^2x=(\tan x)'$ and partial integrate:
$$
2\int{\sec^3(x)dx}=2\int(\tan x)'\sec x dx=2\tan x\sec x -2\int \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^3x}dx$$
In order to solve the last integral, use the formula $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$ and split the integral in two parts:
$$=2\tan x\sec x +2\int \frac{1}{\cos x}dx-2\int \frac{1}{\cos^3 x}dx$$
$$=2\tan x\sec x +2\ln(\sec x+\tan x)-2\int \sec^3 x dx$$
Bring the integral $\int{\sec^3x dx}$ to the other side of the equation:
$$4\int{\sec^3(x)dx}=2\tan x\sec x +2\ln(\sec x+\tan x)$$
In conclusion:
$$\int{\sec^3(x)dx}=\frac{1}{2}\tan x\sec x +\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sec x+\tan x)$$